# Can't change default logo

Tags: css, zabbix

I am trying to change logo in singnin logo and dashboard logo in Zabbix. I put two images inside directory /usr/share/zabbix/img  minilogo.png and biglogo.png

And in both styles in /user/share/zabbix/styles blue-theme.css and dark-theme.css I have done changes:

```
.signin-logo {
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 21px;
  height: 30px;
  background: url(../img/biglogo.png) no-repeat 0; }

.logo {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  width: 95px;
  height: 25px;
  background: url(../img/minilogo.png) no-repeat 0; }


.browser-logo-chrome {
  background: url(../img/minilogo.png) no-repeat 0 0; }

.browser-logo-ff {
  background: url(../img/minilogo.png) no-repeat; }

.browser-logo-ie {
  background: url(../img/minilogo.png) no-repeat 0; }

.browser-logo-opera {
  background: url(../img/minilogoo.png) no-repeat 0; }

.browser-logo-safari {
  background: url(../img/minilogo.png) no-repeat 0; }
```

And in the end I run this command: systemctl restart apache2

But when refresh browser, default logo of zabbix is still there, also when I login. Where is a problem?

Answer (score 0):

Since version 4.2, all of those configurations were changed to Assets folder (/usr/share/zabbix/assets).

Try to change the configuration there and also don't forget to copy the images to the new folder.